# double request only specting one

Tags: php, shopify

I have a webhooks that i use in someone shop's for Shopify, but only this use the information to upload to my server.

When the owner of the shop is click on fullfil item the order going to my site, but in some cases the order appear two times only with one click, i am using php and curl.

this is my php file

```
<?php
//start a session
session_start();

//Webhook enviado por shopify
$webhookContent=        "";
$webhook=               fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .=  fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
$data=      json_decode($webhookContent,true);

//guardar datos ordenes
$file = 'shipping_innata.txt';
$print = print_r($webhookContent, true);
file_put_contents($file, $print, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);


//obtener desde headers el dominio de shopify
$domain_header= $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_DOMAIN'];
//consulta en base 99min
$db =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "plas711", "minut_api");

//comprobar carrier
$shipping=      $data ['shipping_lines']['0']['code'];
$express=       '99minutos.com en menos de 99 minutos (L-V de 9 a 16 hrs) SOLO DF';
$program=       '99minutos.com Programado mismo día (L-V de 9 a 16 hrs) SOLO DF';

//variables obtenidas desde json
$first_name=    $data['shipping_address']['first_name'];
$last_name=     $data['shipping_address']['last_name'];
$email=         $data['email'];
$phone=         $data['shipping_address']['phone'];
$address1=      $data['shipping_address']['address1'];
$address2=      $data['shipping_address']['address2'];
$province=      $data['shipping_address']['province'];
$zip=           $data['shipping_address']['zip'];
$city=          $data['shipping_address']['city'];
$latitude=      $data['shipping_address']['latitude'];
$longitude=     $data['shipping_address']['longitude'];
$note=          $data['note'];
$name=          'Orden: '.$data['name'];
$pago=          $data['gateway'];

if($pago =="Pago contra entrega (SOLO DF Y AREA METROPOLITANA)"){
    $total_price= $data['total_price'];
}
else{
    $total_price=0;
}
//busqueda del correo del propietario de la tienda en base de datos
$mail_db=       "SELECT * FROM tbl_usersettings WHERE store_name = '$domain_header'";
$mail_result=   mysqli_query($db, $mail_db);
$mail_q=        mysqli_fetch_array($mail_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$mail_str=      $mail_q['email'];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//url encode  para producto en bodegas
function request()
{
    global $total_price,$pago,$latitude, $longitude, $address1, $address2, $city, $province, $zip, $email, $phone, $first_name, $last_name, $productos, $name, $db, $shipping, $express, $program;

    // variables
    $api_key=                                   '23894thfpoiq10fapo93fmapo';
    $user_id=                                   '4290583552';
    if ($shipping == $express){
        $delivery_type =    '99minutos';
    }
    else if($shipping == $program){
    $delivery_type = 'Programado';
    }
    $latlng=                                    '19.346857%2C-99.2985648';
    $destination_route=                         urlencode(implode(' ', array($address1,$address2)));
    $destination_locality=                      urlencode($city);
    $destination_administrative_area_level=     urlencode($province);
    $destination_postal_code=                   urlencode($zip);
    $d_latlng=                                  urlencode(implode(',', array($latitude,$longitude)));
    $customer_phone=                            urlencode($phone);
    $nombre =                                   'Cliente: '.implode(' ',array($first_name,$last_name));


    //Variable que pasa al sistema de 99minutos los datos en la seccion de notas
    //$notes=urlencode(implode(', ', array($name,$nombre)));

    //url que sirve para hacer la peticion de envion al sistema de 99minutos
    $request =  "https://das-dot-line-76299minutos.appspot.com/2/delivery/request?";
    $request.=  "api_key=".$api_key."&";
    $request.=  "user_id=".$user_id."&";
    $request.=  "delivery_type=".$delivery_type."&";
    $request.=  "route=ARTEAGA+Y+SALAZAR&";
    $request.=  "street_number=108&";
    $request.=  "neighborhood=Contadero&";
    $request.=  "locality=Mexico&";
    $request.=  "administrative_area_level_1=Distrito+Federal&";
    $request.=  "postal_code=05500&";
    $request.=  "country=Mexico&latlng=".$latlng."&";
    $request.=  "destination-route=".$destination_route."&";
    $request.=  "destination-street_number=&";
    $request.=  "destination-neighborhood=&";
    $request.=  "destination-locality=".$destination_locality."&";
    $request.=  "destination-administrative_area_level=".$destination_administrative_area_level."&";
    $request.=  "destination-postal_code=".$destination_postal_code."&";
    $request.=  "destination-country=Mexico&";
    $request.=  "destination-latlng=".$d_latlng."&";
    $request.=  "customer_email=".$email."&";
    $request.=  "customer_phone=".$customer_phone."&";
    $request.=  "notification_email=&";
    if($pago =="Pago contra entrega (SOLO DF Y AREA METROPOLITANA)"){
            $monto = "Cobro:".$total_price;
            $notes = urlencode((implode(',', array($name,$nombre,$monto))));
            $request.= "notes=".$notes."&";
            $request.= "receivable_order=true&";
            $request.= "amount=".$total_price."&";
        }
        else
        {
            $notes = urlencode((implode(',', array($name,$nombre))));
            $request.= "notes=".$notes."&";
        }
    $request.=  "dispatch=true";
    //funcion curl para enviar la peticion de envio al sistema de 99minutos
    $archivo = 'respaldo_innata.txt';
    $texto = print_r($request, true);
    file_put_contents($archivo, $texto, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    error_log("Request");
    error_log(print_r($request, true));

    $ch_request=curl_init();
    $curl =  curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);

    error_log("Response");
    error_log(print_r($response, TRUE));
    die();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function mailprogramado()
{
        global $domain_header, $name, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $address1, $address2, $province, $zip, $latitude, $longitude, $productos, $pago;
        $to = "ens@99minutos.com";
        $subject = "Envio Tienda Malabares";
        $mail_body = '<html>';
        $mail_body .='<body topmargin="25">';
        $mail_body .='<h2> Dirección de Envio</h2>';
        $mail_body .='<table width="500" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Tienda: </td> <td align="left"> '. $domain_header .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Orden: </td> <td align="left"> '. $name .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Nombre: </td> <td align="left"> '. $first_name .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Apellidos: </td> <td align="left"> '. $last_name .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Correo: </td> <td align="left"> '. $email .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Teléfono: </td> <td align="left"> '. $phone .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Dirección: </td> <td align="left"> '. $address1 .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Dirección: </td> <td align="left"> '. $address2 .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Estado: </td> <td align="left"> '. $province .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Codigo Postal: </td> <td align="left"> '. $zip .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Latitud: </td> <td align="left"> '. $latitude .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Longitud: </td> <td align="left"> '. $longitude .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='<tr> <td width="100" align="center"> Metodo de pago: </td> <td align="left"> '. $pago .' </td> </tr>';
        $mail_body .='</table>';
        $mail_body .='</body>';
        $mail_body .='</html>';
        $headers = "From:ens@99minutos.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
    }
// error_log(print_r($data, true));

if($shipping == $express){
//Notificacion envio depar
mailprogramado();
//realizar pedido de envio
request();
//destruir sesion
session_destroy();
exit();
}
else if($shipping == $program){
//Notificacion envio depar
mailprogramado();
//realizar pedido de envio
request();
//destruir sesion
session_destroy();
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're wondering why do you get several requests from Shopify instead of just one.

I've faced the same problem recently, and I think it's a feature of Webhooks mechanism you have to deal with.

Consider this post: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/webhook-url-is-called-between-2-4-times-220007

Bottomline. You should expect Shopify will hit your endpoint more than once and you have to manage this by yourself to avoid duplicating entities and stuff.

Comment: Well, i looked the post, and if i understand i need to queue the code to solve the problem, but now i dont understand can do this, i don't know in wich part of the code i need to try this.